# Using data from google docs spreadsheet in my HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I've stored some data in a google docs(drive) spreadsheet. I want to know how to import that data into my website using Javascript. I have another table in my website created using HTML. I'd like to know how I can import data from a specific cell in the google spreadsheet to my website.

Comment: this is a different question.